# GitHub Actions: run step only for certain pull request base branches

Tags: github, sonarqube, yaml, github-actions

I have been working on GitHub Actions from quite some time now, and we have a designated workflow in place. The workflow has been written in yaml.

I am trying to put some `if` condition for the `github.ref` and that block of the yaml is being skipped on the run.
It means - if the pull request is raised against X branch - that block of code should run.

Something like this:

```
 
      - name: Branch name check - Running only for DEV branch.. 
        if: ${{contains(github.ref, 'DEV*')}}
        uses: mathrix-education/sonar-scanner@master

        with:
          version: 4.2.0.1873 # required
          typescript: false
          scan: true
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: How are your branches actually named? Probably you should just leave off the * and only use `if: ${{contains(github.ref, 'DEV')}}` to only runn the step if the branch name contains `DEV`.

Comment: I am trying to make a generic yaml where it should be independent of the branch name. But when a PR is raised against that X branch - the checks should happen.

```
  branches:
        - master
        - UAT
        - DEV*
```

Anything after DEV - it should pick it up. Eg: DEV2020. Something like this.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question and have you tried my proposal (leaving off the `*`)?

Comment: @riQQ: Yes - I did try. It is still getting skipped.

Comment: Does my post answer your question? If yes, please accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 10):

We ran into a similar thing when constructing a github workflow. The conditions we are working under:

- We want step 1 to only run on pushes OR pull requests to develop.
- We want step 2 to only run on pull requests to master.
- Steps must be in a single workflow.yaml.

After some research, below is what we came up with. I found Github Actions to be very flexible, with a lot of options that Gitlab and Bitbucket don't have. But that is also the downside and makes it more complex to understand sometimes.

```
---
name: my-workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - main
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: step 1
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' || github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'develop'
        run: echo "Hello develop"
      - name: step 2
        if: github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'master'
        run: echo "Hello master"
```

I would recommend not using if-statements on branches too often. This introduces inconsistencies between the deployments of different branches. For some use cases you may be better of using [github environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) (Enterprise only). For example, if you need to set different environment variables or secrets for different branches. Below is a simple example where you could have two github environments (develop and main) both containing different values for the secret MY_SECRET.

```
name: my-workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Do something
    steps:
      - run: echo "Example using environments corresponding branch names"
    environment: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'main' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' && 'develop' }}
    env:
      MY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to check for the base of the pull request:

`if: ${{contains(github.base_ref, 'DEV')}}`

`github.ref` will contain something like `refs/pull/1/merge` for pull requests.